# Moving selected element to another array

Tags: javascript

I have to create a "Quiz" and I have an array with 10 elements in it, and I am randomly selecting one as the correct answer, and I can't find a way so it doesn't generate it again, but instead sends the element to another array and removes it from the first one, so each time I click next question there is 1 less element in the starting array. Can anyone help? Here's what I've tried so far

```js
var receivedArray = [{
    nameIMGTOP: "15",
    nameIMGTOPafter: "12",
    nameIMGLEFT: "11",
    nameIMGLEFTafter: "12",
    nameTOP: "34"
  },
  {
    nameIMGTOP: "-5",
    nameIMGTOPafter: "-10",
    nameIMGLEFT: "18",
    nameIMGLEFTafter: "22",
    nameTOP: "-3"
  },
  {
    nameIMGTOP: "12",
    nameIMGTOPafter: "",
    nameIMGLEFT: "43",
    nameIMGLEFTafter: "",
    nameTOP: "29"
  }
];


const StartElements = receivedArray;
var SelectedElements = [];
const correctAnswer = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];
const guess1 = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];
const guess2 = StartElements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * StartElements.length), 1)[0];


$("#btn-next").on("click", function() {
  var i = 0;
  while (i < correctAnswer.length) {
    var item = correctAnswer[i];
    console.log(item);
    if (item.selected) {
      correctAnswer.splice(i, 0);
      SelectedElements.push(item);
    } else i++;
    console.log(SelectedElements);
  }
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#test-div").append(
    "<div class=\"row\">\n" +
    "<div class=\"col-6\">\n" +
    "<div class=\"ImageDiv\">" +
    "<img id=\"testImage\" src=\"\" alt='...' align=\"middle\"/>\n" +
    "</div>" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "<h4 class=\"Guess\" id=\"Guess\">ATMINI JŪRNIEKU MEZGLA NOSAUKUMU</h4>\n" +
    "<p id=\"description\"></p>" +
    "<div class=\"col-6 shuffle\">\n" +
    "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >" + correctAnswer.nameLV + "</div><br>" +
    "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >" + guess1.nameLV + "</div><br>" +
    "<div class=\"btn guesses\" >" + guess2.nameLV + "</div><br>" +
    "</div>\n" +
    "</div>\n"
  );
  $("#testImage").attr("src", "../Images/uploads/" + correctAnswer.Image);
  //$("#description").html(correctAnswer.descriptionLV);
  console.log("Bwf");
  $(".shuffle").each(function() {
    var divs = $(this).find('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).remove();
    //the fisher yates algorithm, from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array
    var i = divs.length;
    if (i == 0) return false;
    while (--i) {
      var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      var tempi = divs[i];
      var tempj = divs[j];
      divs[i] = tempj;
      divs[j] = tempi;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) $(divs[i]).appendTo(this);
  });


});
```

```css
#Guess {
  color: #EEA774;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11vw;
  left: 50vw;
}

.guesses {
  background-color: #E89F62;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 17vw;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a {
  color: #F3A361;
  font-size: 25px;
}

a:active {}

ol {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.crumbItem {
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.shuffle {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15vw;
  left: 50vw;
}

#description {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13vw;
  left: 50vw;
  color: white;
  width: 35vw;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#testImage {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-height: 700px;
}

.ImageDiv {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#btn-next {
  outline: none;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#btn-prev {
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="test-div" id="test-div">
    <div class="btn" id="btn-prev" onclick=""><i class="fas fa-angle-left fa-3x"></i></div>
    <div class="btn" id="btn-next" onclick=""><i class="fas fa-angle-right fa-3x"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is dynamically created basing off of the receivedArray

Comment: Also `var someobj = JSON.parse(someValidJSONString)` is the same as `var someobj = someValidJSONString`  so why not just have `const StartElements = <?= json_encode($unserialize) ?>;`

Comment: Lastly `correctAnswer.forEach((answer,i) => { if (answer.selected) { correctAnswer.splice(i,0);
                SelectedElements.push(item); } })`

Comment: Please add a valid example of `<?php echo json_encode($unserialize);?>` as an object

Comment: Your `$("#btn-next").on("click", function(){` needs to be inside the `$(document).ready(function(){ }`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by that

Comment: If your script is not under the HTML, then you will not have a button to assign the click to. Always have event handlers in the document.ready in case you decide to move your script outside the page and link in the head for example